# How to open pdf files with document viewer on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: pdf

I want open my pdf files with Document viewer but I cant. I did it before but know I don't know what is the problem. I have Ubuntu 13.10.I uninstalled it and reinstall it again but it doesn't work.I don't know what is this problem

Comment: Can you provide more information on the problem? E.g. did you get an error message? Can you start `evince` from the terminal to see if you get error message in the terminal?

Comment: when I open this in geraphic mode I dont have any error but I dont try with terminal. would you please tell me with witch command I can try it in terminal? @noleti

Comment: run this command in terminal `evince /path/to/file/File_Name.pdf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug that reported here https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+question/208999

And not solved, but someone suggest to install another pdf viewer(see comment #14):

> For now , try to use another pdf viewer . I suggest acroread (the
>   native acrobat reader in linux).
>
> Enable partners repo . From terminal give :
>
> ```
>    gksudo software-properties-gtk
> ```
>
> go to "Other Software" section and check "Canonical Partners" , close
>   the window and run in terminal
>
> ```
>    sudo apt-get update 
>    sudo apt-get install acroread
> ```